# What is the most accurate and if available complete book of beatles sheet music for piano and/or guitar?

Tags: piano, the-beatles

I'm looking for, primarily, a book of sheet music that has most Beatles recordings for piano/ solo piano. If there's one available specifically for guitar I'd be interested in that as well. I'm not looking for the "easy" or "beginner" versions of anything. I'm trying to get accurate piano parts for playing with a band and for solo piano compositions playing entire songs.

I understand this is partially subjective so I'm looking for the opinions of musicians with experience that might point me in the direction of the best collections. More than one recommendation per answer is fine.

I apologize in advance if this isn't the best place to post this question. If not please point me in the right direction and I'll post it there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding accuracy and completeness, the best source, hands down, is [The Beatles: Complete Scores](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0793518326) from Hal Leonard. The main drawback is the relatively small print—it's not a score you can put on a stand and play from in a dimly lit bar. They give full scores for all songs, showing the separate guitar parts, piano (if present), vocals, etc.

I unfortunately can't speak for piano-only sheet music, but Hal Leonard does have a [two-volume set](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/088188913X) that looks decent.